# how to change width of a ListView when the form width increases?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, listview

I have a simple form with 2 ListViews. When I run the program it opens in default size for form and also for two listviews:

http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/6123/form1default.png

What I need to do is when the form gets expanded (only in WIDTH, I want the height be fixed) the second (wider) listview also be increased in width:

http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/4879/form1widthincrease.png

Can you pleae tell me what properties of form itself and/or second listview I have to change to achive this? Maybe some Events should be considered to add also?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property of the second `ListView` to include [`AnchorStyles.Right`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.anchorstyles.aspx), e.g. `Top, Left, Right` in the properties window in Visual Studio.

You might also want to include `AnchorStyles.Bottom`, to resize the `ListView`(s) when the height of the form changes.

Comment: hmm I tried this but it only moves the list view to right, it does not expand or increase it's width?

Comment: `AnchorStyles` is a bit field, if you're setting the value from C# code then set it to `AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right`

Answer (score 0):

Better you put the two list views in a SplitContainer control and adjust the widths of two listviews. Use the Anchor property of the SplitContainer to increase its width according to the form.